# Error connecting to chef nodes using knife winrm command: "getaddrinfo: No such host is known"

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I'm using `knife winrm` on windows to try to connect to multiple windows nodes (with node names that match the query syntax `'name:FOO*'`), i.e

```
knife winrm 'name:FOO*' 'chef-client -o recipe[recipe_name_to_run]' --winrm-user username --winrm-password 'SuPerPassW0rzor'
```

but the default attribute the knife winrm command uses to try to connect to the nodes is FQDN. In the case of my nodes that doesn't work to connect to them from my workstation, they are not on the same network (or whatever magic network fairy dust is incorrect, their FQDNs are just something like FOOBOO and fab0202-sn.domain.local which my workstation can't connect to).

I tried using the command option `-a` to change the attribute to use for opening the connection, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what the attribute is called to get it to connect using IPs? I tried `-a IP` and `-a ipv4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out (from a random post I found on Google, the documentation I found didn't include any info on the correct attributes for the command). To get `knife winrm` to connect using IPs instead of FQDN, the attribute needs to be set using `-a ipaddress`, so the command would be:

```
knife winrm 'name:FOO*' 'chef-client -o recipe[recipe_name_to_run]' -a ipaddress --winrm-user username --winrm-password 'SuPerPassW0rzor'
```